# Replace text from a specific line

Tags: qt

I'm trying to replace the text of a specific line, but got no success. (i'd searched a lot, but i don't found nothing)

something like:

```
hello
my
friend!
```

replacing line 2 to some text:

```
hello
AEEEHO NEW LINE TEXT
friend!
```

I created a QStringList and tried to read the text line by line and add to this list by changing just the line, but without success.

```
        int line = 1; // to change the second line
        QString newline = "my new text";
        QStringList temp;

        int i = 0;
        foreach(QString curlineSTR, internalCode.split('\n'))
        {
            if(line == i)
                temp << newline;
            else
                temp << curlineSTR;
            i++;
        }

        internalCode = "";
        foreach(QString txt, temp)
            internalCode.append(QString("%1\n").arg(txt));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive that you are looking for [`QRegExp`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QRegExp.html) to deal with newline and do something like this:

```
QString internalcode = "hello\nmy\nfriend!";

int line = 1; // to change the second line
QString newline = "another text";

// Split by newline command
QStringList temp = internalcode.split(QRegExp("\n|\r\n|\r"));
internalcode.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
{
    if (line == i)
        internalcode.append(QString("%0\n").arg(newline));
    else
        internalcode.append(QString("%0\n").arg(temp.at(i)));
}

//Use this to remove the last newline command
internalcode = internalcode.trimmed();

qDebug() << internalcode;
```

And the output:

```
"hello
another text
friend!"
```